# How to print JSON data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

How to print JSON in nodejs json is

```
  {"errors":[
    {"location":"body","param":"email","value":"q","msg":"must be a Email"},{"location":"body","param":"password","value":"q","msg":"5 chars long"}]
    }
```

my function

```
function handleResponse(response) {

        return response.text().then( text => {
            console.log(text);
        });

        return Promise.reject(response);

}
```

console.log(text) produce above json data, how to retrieve msg only and print in my reactjs

Comment: You're looking for `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: i need msg from this json

Comment: text.error.map((e)=> console.log(e.msg)) i think will do for you

Comment: errors is an array so you can use map() to loop each item and print msg from it.

Comment: TypeError: text.error is undefined

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(text).errors.map(error => error.msg));`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood the question.

If you want to get only the message field from the JSON response of your server you just need to `map` your array in this way:

```
function handleResponse (textRes) {
  var jsonRes = {}
  var messages = []

  try {
    jsonRes = JSON.parse(textRes)
  }
  catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject(e)
  }

  messages = jsonRes.errors.map(function (error) {
    return error.msg
  })

  return Promise.resolve(messages)    
}
```

Anyway, you could use some npm package to parse the response automatically. I suggest [cross-fetch](https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch):

```
const fetch = require('cross-fetch')
const API_ENDPOINT = '/api/v1/test-endpoint'

function fetchData () {
  return fetch(API_ENDPOINT)
    .then(function (res) {
      return res.json()
    })
    .then(function (jsonRes) {
      messages = jsonRes.errors.map(function (error) {
        return error.msg
      })

      return Promise.resolve(messages)    
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      //  Catch the error here or let the reject propagate
      //  to the parent function
    })

}
```